# What's wrong with querySelector

Tags: javascript

Based on written code below, the expected result should be returning the DOM element '' in the console, when clicking the 'a' which has keyCode 65. When I run the code and inspect it returns null in the console.

Part of the source code:

```
<audio data-key="65" src="#"></audio>

<script>
    window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){

        const audio = document.querySelector('audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]');
        console.log(audio);

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use es6 placeholder you need to use `backtick` (`) instead of single apostropthe.

```
`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`
```

Other option is just to use string concatenation.

```
'audio[data-key="'+e.keyCode+'"]'
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 5 seconds, because I couldn't find out how to write the backtick character with `inline-code` formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the keycode into the selector string, not include it as a template string.

Change it to this:

```
const audio = document.querySelector('audio[data-key="'+e.keyCode+'"]');
```